# Change interval length in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change the precision of my data so that it is in 100 length intervals.

I was able to do this with plain python, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution using pandas (I am still trying to learn).

**Example:**

This is the starting data

```
start  end    result
600    796    0
796    798    3
798    799    11
799    898    23
898    930   25
930    932   22
932    933   14
933    950   2
```

Rows are merged together so that the data is in 100 intervals, and the values are updated accordingly

```
start  end    result
600    700    0
700    800    3 + 11 + (23 * 1/(898-799))
800    900    (23 * 98/(898-799)) + (25 * 2/(930-898))
900    1000   (25 * 30/(930-898)) + 22 + 14 + 2 + ...
```

Yielding this final result

```
start  end    result
600    700    0
700    800    14.23
800    900    24.33
900    1000   61.44 + ...
```

Comment: I couldn't quite understand your second step `700    800    3 + 11 + (23 * 1/(898-799))
` .Also I assume your round your start and end but then some cases are not rounding but flooring instead.

Comment: @Ricky Since the line ```799    898    23``` corresponds to ```700   800``` and ```800   900```, the value ```23``` is split between those intervals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from `import itertools`, it will be needed soon.

The part of my solution requiring the most part of coding is to "translate"
each source row into a sequence of "intervals" for each hundred range.

To do it, define the following generator function:

```
def IntervGen(st, en, val):
    nxtSt = (st // 100 + 1) * 100
    totalSize = en - st
    origVal = val
    while st < en:
        if en <= nxtSt:      # "en" in the current hundred
            yield st, en, val
            return
        currSize = nxtSt - st
        currVal = origVal * currSize / totalSize
        yield st, nxtSt, currVal
        st = nxtSt
        nxtSt += 100
        val -= currVal
```

The next step is to create an intermediate DataFrame, collecting "intervals"
generated by *IntervGen*:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([ x for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    [ IntervGen(row.start, row.end, row.result) for row in df.itertuples() ]) ],
    columns=['start', 'end', 'value'])
```

For your sample data, the result is:

```
    start  end      value
0     600  700   0.000000
1     700  796   0.000000
2     796  798   3.000000
3     798  799  11.000000
4     799  800   0.232323
5     800  898  22.767677
6     898  900   1.562500
7     900  930  23.437500
8     930  932  22.000000
9     932  933  14.000000
10    933  950   2.000000
```

To facilitate the grouping to be performed soon (by hundred ranges),
change a little *start* column (round down to the full hundred):

```
df2.start = df2.start // 100 * 100
```

And to generate the final result, run:

```
res = df2.groupby('start').value.sum().rename('result').reset_index()
res.insert(1, 'end', res.start + 100)
```

The result (*res* DataFrame for your sample data) is:

```
   start   end     result
0    600   700   0.000000
1    700   800  14.232323
2    800   900  24.330177
3    900  1000  61.437500
```

## Edit following the comment as of 2020-06-30

There is nothing weird in the result you presented in your comment.
Probably the corresponding source data is:

```
start  end    result
11400  11443  0
11443  11454  1
11461  11472  2
```

and each of these rows has been translated into a **single** output interval,
with original values, as both *start* and *end* are within the same hundred.

Note also that this is the "initial" result saved in *df2* and after
`df2.start = df2.start // 100 * 100` all these *start* values
will be rounded down to *11400*.

Along with other values with *start* rounded down to *11400* they
will be summed up and put in the final result as `11400  11500` (as
*start* and *end*) + the corresponding sum of values.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with larger numbers (>10^4), where I get
``
11400  11443      0
11443  11454      1
11461  11472      2
```

Comment: Just saw the edit. I see, it makes sense now. Great solution!